# Virtualbox ошибка запуска ВМ

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, virtual-hosts

Недавно поставил `Debian 10` на свой ПК, после чего установил на него `VirtualBox`, создал виртуальную машину, и столкнулся с проблемой. ВМ **не** запускается, а выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows.

The virtual machine 'Windows' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {5047460a-265d-4538-b23e-ddba5fb84976}
```

Поискав в интернете способы решения в интернете, нашел только рекомендации по типу "`удалите kb:3004394 обновление Windows`" (А ведь у меня `Debian`), включите "`Intel Virtualization Technology`" (У меня эта опция включена) и так далее.

В общем, решения из интернета результата не дали.

Прошу помочь в решении этой проблемы. Спасибо!

Comment: https://www.ostechnix.com/solve-result-code-ns_error_failure-0x80004005-virtualbox-error-arch-linux/

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1198060 не помогает?

Comment: VirtualBox стал совсем плохой, лучше используйте https://www.vmware.com/ru/products/workstation-player.html, он бесплатный

Comment: Читайте логи запуска виртуальной машины в каталоге с этой самой виртуальной машиной

Comment: `vboxconfig` запускал?